# Create tuple of multiple items n Times in Python

Tags: python, tuples

A list can be created n times:

```
a = [['x', 'y']]*3 # Output = [['x', 'y'], ['x', 'y'], ['x', 'y']]
```

But I want to make a tuple in such a way but it not returning the similar result as in the list. I am doing the following:

```
a = (('x','y'))*4 # Output = ('x', 'y', 'x', 'y', 'x', 'y', 'x', 'y')
Expected_output = (('x', 'y'), ('x', 'y'), ('x', 'y'), ('x', 'y'))
```

Any suggestions ? Thanks.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The outer parentheses are only grouping parentheses. You need to add a comma to make the outer enclosure a tuple:

```
a = (('x','y'),)*4
print(a)
# (('x', 'y'), ('x', 'y'), ('x', 'y'), ('x', 'y'))
```

For context, it wouldn't make sense to get a tuple while doing `f = (x + y)`, for example.

---

In order to define a singleton tuple, a comma is usually required:

```
a = (5)  # integer
a = (5,) # tuple
a = 5,   # tuple, parens are not compulsory
```

---

On a side note, duplicating items across nested containers would require more than just a simple mult. operation. Consider your first operation for example:

```
>>> a = [['x', 'y']]*3
>>> # modify first item
...
>>> a[0][0] = 'n'
>>> a
[['n', 'y'], ['n', 'y'], ['n', 'y']]
```

There is essentially no first item - the parent list contains just one list object duplicated across different indices. This might not be particularly worrisome for tuples as they are *immutable* any way.

Consider using the more correct recipe:

```
>>> a = [['x', 'y'] for _ in range(3)]
>>> a[0][0] = 'n'
>>> a
[['n', 'y'], ['x', 'y'], ['x', 'y']]
```

Comment: Thanks. But whats is the reason for this small difference ?

Comment: This is to differentiate between  closed braces used as a bracket (for example `(5) => 5`) and to represent a tuple.

Comment: Do note that the final result is a tuple containing four references to the same tuple (`id(a[0]) == id(a[1])` evaluates to `True`). Tuples are immutable, so it doesn't matter, but if you had four of the same list inside your tuple and modified one, the results could be surprising.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski I'll add that as a comment regarding the list part particularly. Good you noted

Answer (score 0):

This is just a minor change to the [main answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40568804/4561887). I just needed to see this a little more concretely for my case, is all.

### Tuple of `N` `None`s

For anyone just trying to get a tuple of N elements of `None`, or some other simple value, to initialize some tuple variables, it would look like this:

```py
N = 3
# Create `(None, None, None)`
tuple_of_nones = (None,) * N  

# Create `(3, 3, 3, 3, 3)`
tuple_of_five_threes = (3,) * 5

# etc.
```

Example run and output in an interpreter:

```py
>>> N = 3
>>> tuple_of_nones = (None,) * N
>>> tuple_of_nones
(None, None, None)

>>> tuple_of_five_threes = (3,) * 5
>>> tuple_of_five_threes
(3, 3, 3, 3, 3)
```